# I want to match two files based on different fields in the two files using awk?

Tags: awk

Hi I have a big data set and i want to match two files based on $5 from file 1 and $1 or $3 of file 2 and print file 1 which match with file 2. In addition, i want to print $5 and $6 of file 2 in file 1 after matching.

**file 1**

```
7   81  1   47  32070  
7   83  1   67  29446  
7   92  1   84  28234
```

**file 2**

```
32070        0      0   19360101   HF 8   0 M C  
28234        0      0   19350101   HF 8   0 M C  
124332       0      0   19340101   HF 8   0 M C  
29446        0      0   19340101   HF 8   0 M C
```

**I would like to print like this**

```
7   81  1   47  32070  HF 8  
7   83  1   67  29446  HF 8  
7   92  1   84  28234  HF 8
```

Comment: Which one is big or both?

Comment: file 1 is bigger than file 2

Answer (score 3):

This awk  one-liner should do the job:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$5 FS $6;next}$0=$0 FS a[$NF]' f2 f1
```

If give it a test on your example input files:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$5 FS $6;next}$0=$0 FS a[$NF]' f2 f1
7 81 1 47 32070 HF 8
7 83 1 67 29446 HF 8
7 92 1 84 28234 HF 8
```

Comment: it works for the given example but i have made some problem when i specify my columns which are going to be matched. I look forward your response

Comment: The question is revised